# Get input text from user and save it on webserver using iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is there a way to capture input text in iPhone App and send that text to webserver?

How can we achieve this?

Basically I want to get user's email address by having them sign up for newsletter inside the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple web service that takes the parameters you need to pass and add them to a database. Here's a simple example with PHP to save a username and password to a mysql database. Below it you will find how to send it from within the App using a POST request:

```
<?

// check if email and password are not blank
if(trim($_POST['email']) != '' && trim($_POST['password']) != '') 
{
    $emailQuery = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    $passwordQuery = md5($_POST['password']);
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'username';
    $dbpassword = 'password';
    $dbname = 'databasename';

    /* connect to the db */
    $link = mysql_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpassword) or die ('Cannot connect to the DB');
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

    /* insert the data into the db */
    $query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES ('','$emailQuery','$passwordQuery')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
    echo "Database updated";
    @mysql_close($link);

} else echo "Mandatory parameters missing";

?>
```

Then from your App you can send the post request by using NSURLConnection. I am using a synchronous request for the sake of simplicity but recommend that you check the documentation for NSURLConnection and how implement asynchronous requests and read the response through delegate methods:

```
// login and password are both UITextField instances
        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",self.login.text, self.password.text];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/webservice.php"]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // To see what the response from your server is, NSLog returnString to the console or use it whichever way you want it.
    NSLog (@"%@", returnString);
```

I hope it helps.
Rog

Answer (score 0):

App Guidelines 17.2 states that apps that ask for user's personal information (such as email and birthday) will be rejected.

Comment: Your quote is inaccurate, here's what Apple has to say:"Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected". Keyword is "IN ORDER TO FUNCTION".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (but like Eimantas said it will be rejected) is to do a http get request to a php file on your webserver with like  *url = www.example.com/myiphonescript.php?q=%@, searchTerm. searchTerm is your textfield input. Then save this value in the php script to a DB or whatever you want to do with it!